# How to split this string

Tags: java, string, split

I have following string that I need to split by `"_Folder43\"` so that I get just the image name in the second element of the array.

```
E:\generated\_Folder43\image4565.jpg
```

So far I have following code

```
  String[] tokens = imageLoc.split("_Folder43\"); //backslash escapes the double quotes!
  imageLoc = tokens[1];
  System.out.println(imageLoc);
```

First line in above code is where the problem is because the back slash in there escapes the double quotes and hence not allowing to end the string.

Required output **image4565.jpg**

Comment: May I know the reason for splitting. We can get the filename as below imageLoc.substring(imageLoc.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,imageLoc.length());

Comment: Agreed. It can be even simpler. You don't need the last argument: `imageLoc = imageLoc.substring(imageLoc.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);`

Comment: Sad panda for doing this in the view layer.

Comment: I removed the JSP tag. Writing bad Java code in a JSP file instead of a normal Java class doesn't make it a JSP specific problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when doing so in a normal Java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes with another backslash: `"_Folder43\\"`. However, since `String.split()` takes a regex, you also have to escape the resulting backslash in the regex: `String[] tokens = imageLoc.split("_Folder43\\\\");`

Comment: No problem. If you haven't already, I would recommend considering rob's suggestion. Using the File API seems like a much better solution to the code presented.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use string operations to work with file paths.

If you're using Java 6 or older, use the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API instead:

```
package com.example.file;

import java.io.File;

public class FileExample2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "E:\\generated\\_Folder43\\image4565.jpg";
        File f = new File(path);
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
}
```

If you're using Java 7 or newer, use the [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) API.  Unfortunately, I don't have Java 7 handy to test it, but I think it would go something like this (please feel free to correct me if there are errors):

```
public class PathExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "E:\\generated\\_Folder43\\image4565.jpg";
        Path p = Paths.get(path);
        System.out.println(p.getFileName().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of split use the substring as below.

```
     String imageLoc ="E:\\generated\\_Folder43\\image4565.jpg";

     imageLoc = imageLoc.substring(imageLoc.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,imageLoc.length());

     System.out.println(imageLoc);

     or 

     String imageLoc ="E:/generated/_Folder43/image4565.jpg";

     imageLoc = imageLoc.substring(imageLoc.lastIndexOf("/")+1,imageLoc.length());
```

Comment: `imageLoc.substring(imageLoc.lastIndexOf("/")+1);` is shorter, it will include all text until the end of the string